# How to merge latest revision of third-party library in our codebase?

Tags: git

Our application is based on a third-party software whose license we purchased.The codebase is like:

```
code/
   src/
   headers/
   custom/
```

Our codebase is maintained in our own-hosted Bitbucket git. We have been doing our development mostly in `custom` folder.

The third party has updated their software and we want to merge their updated software in our codebase. They will send us the source in zip folder. How can I merge that in our `master` branch of the codebase? 
What's the best method? I am completely new to git hence the question.

I am thinking something like:

1. Clone the `master` branch
2. Copy files from the zip folder root (CTRL+C, CTLR+V) to the root of the cloned master.
3. `git status` to check what files have been changed
4. Go through each file and resolve conflicts
5. `git add *`
6. `git commit -m <commit-message>`
7. `git push origin master`

Is this the best way to do it ?

Comment: The best method is to not use copy-paste as an import mechanism.  Use a language that has proper support for libraries, and use the libraries.  Importing source code is not the proper way to make use of a library.  You will solve (or perhaps just avoid!) many problems by addressing the root cause.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Our codebase is forked off the third party software. We have made changes to it over the time but majority of it is still the same, especially folder structures.

Comment: That's good!  Keep your forked version in a separate project and create a proper library from it.  Then use that library in your main project.  Don't corrupt the main project by importing source code into it.